# Websocket onmessage not firing - java based server

Tags: javascript, java, websocket

My project is basically to get websocket's working with a java based server in realtime.  Parts for the code I may have pulled from forums on the web.  The java based server works to a degree in that I can test it with a (non web) application client - but the objective is to get it working to communicate with a web based client.

The issue is with the onmessage event listener.  In my efforts the server can successfully send a message to the web client and the web client can read it - but it only works on a one time basis.  The onmessage event in the client can't receive any more than one message from the server at a time.  The server literally has to restart and the browser has to restart which is not what I'm looking for.  Eventually I'm looking to have the web-client to update on a realtime basis while communicating with the server in java - similar to a chat program.

I'm looking for ways to make sure that the event listener is maintained but not sure how to do this.  Also I'm not sure if the webclient needs to be on a thread but also am not sure how to do this.

**Please visit my github profile:  https://github.com/russellbrown100?tab=repositories**

--------------------------   The Java Server -----------------------------

```
    /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package imageserver;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.Base64;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;;





/**
 *
 * @author Russell Brown
 */
public class ImageServer {


    public static ServerSocket server;
    public static Socket clientSocket;

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here


        try
        {


                server = new ServerSocket(6666); 
                System.out.println("server created");
                clientSocket = server.accept(); 
                System.out.println("client accepted");

                InputStream inputStream = clientSocket.getInputStream();
                OutputStream outputStream = clientSocket.getOutputStream();
                doHandShakeToInitializeWebSocketConnection(inputStream, outputStream);

                int counter = 0;

                while (true)
                {

                    String string = "hello" + counter;

                    outputStream.write(encode(string));

                    counter++;

                    Thread.sleep(10);

                }





        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

    }



    public static byte[] encode(String mess) throws IOException{
        byte[] rawData = mess.getBytes();

        int frameCount  = 0;
        byte[] frame = new byte[10];

        frame[0] = (byte) 129;

        if(rawData.length <= 125){
            frame[1] = (byte) rawData.length;
            frameCount = 2;
        }else if(rawData.length >= 126 && rawData.length <= 65535){
            frame[1] = (byte) 126;
            int len = rawData.length;
            frame[2] = (byte)((len >> 8 ) & (byte)255);
            frame[3] = (byte)(len & (byte)255); 
            frameCount = 4;
        }else{
            frame[1] = (byte) 127;
            int len = rawData.length;
            frame[2] = (byte)((len >> 56 ) & (byte)255);
            frame[3] = (byte)((len >> 48 ) & (byte)255);
            frame[4] = (byte)((len >> 40 ) & (byte)255);
            frame[5] = (byte)((len >> 32 ) & (byte)255);
            frame[6] = (byte)((len >> 24 ) & (byte)255);
            frame[7] = (byte)((len >> 16 ) & (byte)255);
            frame[8] = (byte)((len >> 8 ) & (byte)255);
            frame[9] = (byte)(len & (byte)255);
            frameCount = 10;
        }

        int bLength = frameCount + rawData.length;

        byte[] reply = new byte[bLength];

        int bLim = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<frameCount;i++){
            reply[bLim] = frame[i];
            bLim++;
        }
        for(int i=0; i<rawData.length;i++){
            reply[bLim] = rawData[i];
            bLim++;
        }

        return reply;
    }


    private static void doHandShakeToInitializeWebSocketConnection(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String data = new Scanner(inputStream,"UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\r\\n\\r\\n").next();

        Matcher get = Pattern.compile("^GET").matcher(data);

        if (get.find()) {
            Matcher match = Pattern.compile("Sec-WebSocket-Key: (.*)").matcher(data);
            match.find();                 

            byte[] response = null;
            try {
                response = ("HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n"
                        + "Connection: Upgrade\r\n"
                        + "Upgrade: websocket\r\n"
                        + "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: "
                        + DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(
                                MessageDigest
                                .getInstance("SHA-1")
                                .digest((match.group(1) + "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11")
                                        .getBytes("UTF-8")))
                        + "\r\n\r\n")
                        .getBytes("UTF-8");
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                outputStream.write(response, 0, response.length);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {

        }
    }


    private static void printInputStream(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        int len = 0;            
        byte[] b = new byte[1024];
        //rawIn is a Socket.getInputStream();
        while(true){
            len = inputStream.read(b);
            if(len!=-1){

                byte rLength = 0;
                int rMaskIndex = 2;
                int rDataStart = 0;
                //b[0] is always text in my case so no need to check;
                byte data = b[1];
                byte op = (byte) 127;
                rLength = (byte) (data & op);

                if(rLength==(byte)126) rMaskIndex=4;
                if(rLength==(byte)127) rMaskIndex=10;

                byte[] masks = new byte[4];

                int j=0;
                int i=0;
                for(i=rMaskIndex;i<(rMaskIndex+4);i++){
                    masks[j] = b[i];
                    j++;
                }

                rDataStart = rMaskIndex + 4;

                int messLen = len - rDataStart;

                byte[] message = new byte[messLen];

                for(i=rDataStart, j=0; i<len; i++, j++){
                    message[j] = (byte) (b[i] ^ masks[j % 4]);
                }

                System.out.println(new String(message)); 

                b = new byte[1024];

            }
        }
    }



}
```

---------------------------------- The Web Client -----------------------------------------

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">

<title>WebSocket Client</title>

 <script type="text/javascript">

      var wsocket;      

      function connect() {         

          wsocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:6666");          
          wsocket.onopen = onopen;
          wsocket.onmessage = onmessage;
          wsocket.onclose = onclose; 


      }

      function onopen() {
        document.writeln("opened");
      }

      function onmessage(event) { 

         document.writeln(event.data);



      }

      function onclose(e) {
            document.writeln("closed");
      }

      window.addEventListener("load", connect, false);




  </script>




</head>

<body>




</body>

</html>
```

Your assistance will be appreciated.

**Please visit my github profile:  https://github.com/russellbrown100?tab=repositories**

Comment: Another question I have about websockets - on a web client, when a websocket receives messages does it close automatically?  if so then should I be re-creating it?  Are there limitations on this?

Comment: Seems to actually work in chrome - but not in IE or Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION:   Had discovered that browsers have development tools which one can debug.  The issue was entirely an IE thing.  Had removed document.writeln and added the response to a div element like so:

```
  function onmessage(event) { 

  console.log(event.data);

  var div = document.getElementsByName("mydiv")[0];

  div.innerHTML += event.data;

    // document.writeln(event.data);


  }
```

Sending a thanks for all your support.